# Meteor Template functions and 3rd party js

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I found [this neat effect on bootsnipp](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-avatar-blur) which I was able to make work if I put all the blur js into `Template.myItem.onRendered(function(){//blur code here});`.

However, I have expanded my functionality a bit and now the images can get changed when you click on something and I would expect the blur effect to happen automatically. I was able to make it work again by throwing the whole of the blur js into the `Template.myItem.events({'click': function() {//blur code here}});`.

Obviously, there must be a better way to run this blur code..preferably keeping it in its own file and just calling this.Blur(); or something to that effect but so far I keep striking out and I am not sure if this would require me going as far as turning it into a package or something like that.

The bootsnipp js only:

```
var mul_table = [
        512,512,456,512,328,456,335,512,405,328,271,456,388,335,292,512,
        454,405,364,328,298,271,496,456,420,388,360,335,312,292,273,512,
        482,454,428,405,383,364,345,328,312,298,284,271,259,496,475,456,
        437,420,404,388,374,360,347,335,323,312,302,292,282,273,265,512,
        497,482,468,454,441,428,417,405,394,383,373,364,354,345,337,328,
        320,312,305,298,291,284,278,271,265,259,507,496,485,475,465,456,
        446,437,428,420,412,404,396,388,381,374,367,360,354,347,341,335,
        329,323,318,312,307,302,297,292,287,282,278,273,269,265,261,512,
        505,497,489,482,475,468,461,454,447,441,435,428,422,417,411,405,
        399,394,389,383,378,373,368,364,359,354,350,345,341,337,332,328,
        324,320,316,312,309,305,301,298,294,291,287,284,281,278,274,271,
        268,265,262,259,257,507,501,496,491,485,480,475,470,465,460,456,
        451,446,442,437,433,428,424,420,416,412,408,404,400,396,392,388,
        385,381,377,374,370,367,363,360,357,354,350,347,344,341,338,335,
        332,329,326,323,320,318,315,312,310,307,304,302,299,297,294,292,
        289,287,285,282,280,278,275,273,271,269,267,265,263,261,259];


var shg_table = [
         9, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
        17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 
        19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20,
        20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21,
        21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
        21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
        22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22,
        22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23,
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
        23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
        24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
        24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
        24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24,
        24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24 ];


function stackBlurCanvasRGBA( canvas, top_x, top_y, width, height, radius )
{
    if ( isNaN(radius) || radius < 1 ) return;
    radius |= 0;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var imageData;

    try {
      try {
        imageData = context.getImageData( top_x, top_y, width, height );
      } catch(e) {

        // NOTE: this part is supposedly only needed if you want to work with local files
        // so it might be okay to remove the whole try/catch block and just use
        // imageData = context.getImageData( top_x, top_y, width, height );
        try {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead");
            imageData = context.getImageData( top_x, top_y, width, height );
        } catch(e) {
            alert("Cannot access local image");
            throw new Error("unable to access local image data: " + e);
            return;
        }
      }
    } catch(e) {
      alert("Cannot access image");
      throw new Error("unable to access image data: " + e);
    }

    var pixels = imageData.data;

    var x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw, r_sum, g_sum, b_sum, a_sum, 
    r_out_sum, g_out_sum, b_out_sum, a_out_sum,
    r_in_sum, g_in_sum, b_in_sum, a_in_sum, 
    pr, pg, pb, pa, rbs;

    var div = radius + radius + 1;
    var w4 = width << 2;
    var widthMinus1  = width - 1;
    var heightMinus1 = height - 1;
    var radiusPlus1  = radius + 1;
    var sumFactor = radiusPlus1 * ( radiusPlus1 + 1 ) / 2;

    var stackStart = new BlurStack();
    var stack = stackStart;
    for ( i = 1; i < div; i++ )
    {
        stack = stack.next = new BlurStack();
        if ( i == radiusPlus1 ) var stackEnd = stack;
    }
    stack.next = stackStart;
    var stackIn = null;
    var stackOut = null;

    yw = yi = 0;

    var mul_sum = mul_table[radius];
    var shg_sum = shg_table[radius];

    for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    {
        r_in_sum = g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = 0;

        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi] );
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1] );
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2] );
        a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3] );

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
        a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

        stack = stackStart;

        for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ )
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack.a = pa;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        for( i = 1; i < radiusPlus1; i++ )
        {
            p = yi + (( widthMinus1 < i ? widthMinus1 : i ) << 2 );
            r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[p])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
            g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[p+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[p+2])) * rbs;
            a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[p+3])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;
            a_in_sum += pa;

            stack = stack.next;
        }


        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            pixels[yi+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            if ( pa != 0 )
            {
                pa = 255 / pa;
                pixels[yi]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[yi+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
                pixels[yi+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum) * pa;
            } else {
                pixels[yi] = pixels[yi+1] = pixels[yi+2] = 0;
            }

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
            a_sum -= a_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
            a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

            p =  ( yw + ( ( p = x + radius + 1 ) < widthMinus1 ? p : widthMinus1 ) ) << 2;

            r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]);
            g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]);
            b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]);
            a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]);

            r_sum += r_in_sum;
            g_sum += g_in_sum;
            b_sum += b_in_sum;
            a_sum += a_in_sum;

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
            g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
            b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
            a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;
            a_in_sum -= pa;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += 4;
        }
        yw += width;
    }


    for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
    {
        g_in_sum = b_in_sum = a_in_sum = r_in_sum = g_sum = b_sum = a_sum = r_sum = 0;

        yi = x << 2;
        r_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pr = pixels[yi]);
        g_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pg = pixels[yi+1]);
        b_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pb = pixels[yi+2]);
        a_out_sum = radiusPlus1 * ( pa = pixels[yi+3]);

        r_sum += sumFactor * pr;
        g_sum += sumFactor * pg;
        b_sum += sumFactor * pb;
        a_sum += sumFactor * pa;

        stack = stackStart;

        for( i = 0; i < radiusPlus1; i++ )
        {
            stack.r = pr;
            stack.g = pg;
            stack.b = pb;
            stack.a = pa;
            stack = stack.next;
        }

        yp = width;

        for( i = 1; i <= radius; i++ )
        {
            yi = ( yp + x ) << 2;

            r_sum += ( stack.r = ( pr = pixels[yi])) * ( rbs = radiusPlus1 - i );
            g_sum += ( stack.g = ( pg = pixels[yi+1])) * rbs;
            b_sum += ( stack.b = ( pb = pixels[yi+2])) * rbs;
            a_sum += ( stack.a = ( pa = pixels[yi+3])) * rbs;

            r_in_sum += pr;
            g_in_sum += pg;
            b_in_sum += pb;
            a_in_sum += pa;

            stack = stack.next;

            if( i < heightMinus1 )
            {
                yp += width;
            }
        }

        yi = x;
        stackIn = stackStart;
        stackOut = stackEnd;
        for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
        {
            p = yi << 2;
            pixels[p+3] = pa = (a_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum;
            if ( pa > 0 )
            {
                pa = 255 / pa;
                pixels[p]   = ((r_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                pixels[p+1] = ((g_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
                pixels[p+2] = ((b_sum * mul_sum) >> shg_sum ) * pa;
            } else {
                pixels[p] = pixels[p+1] = pixels[p+2] = 0;
            }

            r_sum -= r_out_sum;
            g_sum -= g_out_sum;
            b_sum -= b_out_sum;
            a_sum -= a_out_sum;

            r_out_sum -= stackIn.r;
            g_out_sum -= stackIn.g;
            b_out_sum -= stackIn.b;
            a_out_sum -= stackIn.a;

            p = ( x + (( ( p = y + radiusPlus1) < heightMinus1 ? p : heightMinus1 ) * width )) << 2;

            r_sum += ( r_in_sum += ( stackIn.r = pixels[p]));
            g_sum += ( g_in_sum += ( stackIn.g = pixels[p+1]));
            b_sum += ( b_in_sum += ( stackIn.b = pixels[p+2]));
            a_sum += ( a_in_sum += ( stackIn.a = pixels[p+3]));

            stackIn = stackIn.next;

            r_out_sum += ( pr = stackOut.r );
            g_out_sum += ( pg = stackOut.g );
            b_out_sum += ( pb = stackOut.b );
            a_out_sum += ( pa = stackOut.a );

            r_in_sum -= pr;
            g_in_sum -= pg;
            b_in_sum -= pb;
            a_in_sum -= pa;

            stackOut = stackOut.next;

            yi += width;
        }
    }

    context.putImageData( imageData, top_x, top_y );

}

function BlurStack()
{
    this.r = 0;
    this.g = 0;
    this.b = 0;
    this.a = 0;
    this.next = null;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var BLUR_RADIUS = 40;
  var sourceImages = [];

  $('.src-image').each(function(){
    sourceImages.push($(this).attr('src'));
  });

  $('.avatar img').each(function(index){
    $(this).attr('src', sourceImages[index] );
  });

  var drawBlur = function(canvas, image) {
    var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
    stackBlurCanvasRGBA(canvas, 0, 0, w, h, BLUR_RADIUS);
  }; 


  $('.card canvas').each(function(index){
    var canvas = $(this)[0];

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = sourceImages[index];

    image.onload = function() {
      drawBlur(canvas, image);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What's exactly the issue with making it a package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into the specific implementation for this blur code, I believe what you are looking for it Meteor.methods. With Meteor.methods you could do something like this:

blur.js:

```
Meteor.methods({
    blurStuff: function(params){
        // all the code to handle the blur.
        // similar to how you are handling it in the event.
    }
});
```

myItem.js:

```
Template.myItem.events({
    'click': function(){
        // Do some stuff when myItem is clicked, or not, then:
        Meteor.call('blur', {params});
    }
});
```

otherThing.js:

```
Template.otherThing.onRender(function(){
    //Do some rendering stuff, or not, then:
    Meteor.call('blur', {params});
);
```

Blur is nicely hanging out in the Meteor.methods and is now relatively portable. You can call the method in various places and can use the blur.js file in various projects. Now if you would like to package it up you can just package up blur.js (with the appropriate package files) and you will have a nice little blur plugin. However, if you want to just move blur.js between projects, that would be fine too.